# Missing a trick for minimizing KL-divergence?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to find $\alpha^*$ and $\beta^*$ to minimize the
Kullback-Leibler-Divergenz $D_{\text{KL}}(p, q)$ between $p(x) = \frac{1}{2} N(x| \mu, \sigma^2) + \frac{1}{2} N(x|\lambda, \gamma^2)$ and $N(\alpha, \beta^2)$.

I started by plugging the distributions into the KL Formula
\begin{align*}
& D_{\text{KL}}(p, q)= \\
& -\int \frac{1}{2}\left(N\left(x \mid \mu, \sigma^2\right)+N\left(x \mid \lambda, \gamma^2\right)\right) \cdot \ln \left(N\left(\alpha, \beta^2\right)\right) d x \\
& +\int \frac{1}{2}\left(N\left(x \mid \mu, \sigma^2\right)+N\left(x \mid \lambda, \gamma^2\right)\right) \cdot \ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\left(N\left(x \mid \mu, \sigma^2\right)+\mu\left(x \mid \lambda, \gamma^2\right)\right)\right) d x \\
\end{align*}
and then I would differenciate with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, set to Zero and solve.

However, I don't know how to deal with these integrals. I also don't see a way to simplify the expression.
I guess that I'm missing some trick here?